# How do I restart a NSTimer?

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer

Thank you in advance.

I am developing a game that runs on a timer. I have a label on the view *countdown. I am using a NSTimer *countdownTimer to run 120 seconds (2:00). That is when the game is over. Also, at the same time...I am running a transition timer that modals to another view controller.

I have it set up where the next view the player can select "Play Again". I have it set up where it goes back to the original view. However, how do I reset the *countdownTimer to run again from 2:00?

```
- (IBAction)playAgain:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self setTimer];
[self GameOver];
[self Score];
[self timerRun];
countdown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2:00"];
}
```

This is the button to play again. The countdown text does not reset. Here is my NSTimer for *countdownTimer

```
-(void) timerRun {
secondsCount = secondsCount - 1;
int minuts = secondsCount / 60;
int seconds = secondsCount - (minuts * 60);

NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2d:%.2d", minuts, seconds];
countdown.text = timerOutput;

if (secondsCount == 0) {
    [countdownTimer invalidate];
    countdownTimer = nil;
}
}

-(void) setTimer {
secondsCount= 120;
countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

When it resets, it just stays at zero instead of going back to 2:00

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that your setTimer method is being called on playAgain? Check if the countdownTimer is being reinitialized. I tested your code on mine and seems to be fine.

Comment: Why do you call `timerRun` in `playAgain`?

Comment: First you should invalidate your timer before -(void) setTimer .. by if (timer) {invalidate} . then you should create new timer and initialize the new state. you can not reset timer directly.

Comment: Thanks for all the hints. instead of using a play again button on a modal, I am using an alert view. For others to see after setting the alertView timer to 123 seconds, I invalidate the countDown Timer and the AlertTimer to have it run again.